# Symfony form to edit multiple objects at once

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a form that displays some sort of table to edit all of my Task objects which consist of a name and a description. You're also supposed to be able to delete and add new Tasks. When you're done, everything is supposed to be updated inside my database at once. How would I go about this with Symfony Forms?

Comment: I would suggest using a bundle/library like easyadmin, some sonataadminbundle or whatever. because what you describe as so blatantly is a lot of work and since you *appear* to have little to no experience with symfony forms, why start large?

Comment: Sounds like a custom implementation of form [CollectionType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan yes, I actually got it to work with CollectionType, thank you :)